# Uncaught TypeError : undefined is not a function & Uncaught RangeError : maximum call stack size exceeded Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been following the Angular2 quicstart using javascript in the purpose of learning the Angular2 framework.. I've been doing exactly like the guidelines told me but I'm having an errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function angular2-all.umd.js:3528
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded angular2-polyfills.js:143
```

I'm not sure if I missed something, this is the file structure of my app

- app/

  - app.component.js
  - boot.js
- node_modules/
- index.html
- package.json

and this is the code base

app.component.js

```
(function (app) {

    app.AppComponent = ng.core
        .Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
            }
        });

})(window.app || (window.app == {}));
```

boot.js

```
(function(app) {

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular 2</title>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.component.js"></script>
    <script src="app/boot.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading..</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I followed the quickstart perfectly, but I'm not sure on where did I missed since I'm new to Angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little almost unnoticeable typo in your code that makes a huge difference. This is your IIFE in `app.component.js` file:

```
(function (app) {
    // ...
})(window.app || (window.app == {}));
// comparison operator ------^
```

Note, that you use comparison operator, while you want **assignment**:

```
(function (app) {
    // ...
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: yes I did a typo, thanks for noticing ! unfortunately that didn't solve the problem though... I still got the error message

Comment: Really? Because I actually tested your code - that's how I realised about this typo. It did fix the problem though.

Comment: could you share me the tested codes ? or is it possible that browser version caused this issue ?

Comment: Did you try https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/js/plnkr.html ?

Comment: tried it and it returns Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function collection.ts:65 so I guess my chrome has an issue about it ? I run it on ubuntu though

Comment: I tried it on windows and it doesn't have any errors.. so I guess browser issue has something to do with it.. anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: and yes based on this article http://gurustop.net/blog/2015/10/07/angularjs2-internet-explorer-support, I read angular2 support chrome version 45 above, meanwhile the installed version on my ubuntu was 35 so yeah, I think for sure this is browser issue :)

Comment: Oh, then for sure! Try to update it to see if it's okay?